# How to find missing data in a range of dates in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table (ATTENDANCE) contains the attendance of the employee as following

```
EMPNO   DATE
2     07/11/2016
2     07/12/2016
3     07/12/2016
6     07/13/2016
7     07/13/2016
```

which contains the employee number(empno) and the attended date(date)

And another table (EMPLOYEES) contains all the empolyees in the company for example like this

```
EMPNO   NAME
1       Musa
2       Ali 
3       Khalid
6       James
7       Sara
```

I can find if an employee was absent in a specific date by using this code

```
select empno 
from EMPLOYEES 
where empno not in (select empno 
               from ATTENDANCE
               where date = '07/11/2016')
```

I want to retreive the list of absent employees in any day between a specific range
I tried to use this query

```
select empno 
from EMPLOYEES 
where empno not in (select empno 
               from ATTENDANCE
               where  date between '07/11/2016' and  '07/13/2016'  )
```

but this will give me those who are absent in **all** the days in this range , **If an employee was absent in one day only it will not retreive it**

I want a query to retreive the empno and the date where the employee was absent?

**Update:**
I tried this too , as **sagi** mentioned

```
select empno 
from EMPLOYEES 
where empno not in (select empno
    from ATTENDANCE
    group by empno
    having count(empno) = to_date(' 07/09/2016','mm,dd,rrrr') - to_date('07/13/2016','mm,dd,rrrr') )
```

this will work but it will not give me in **which date the employee was absent**

Comment: In your output do you need to distinguish between "week days" or "work days" on the one hand, and "weekend or holiday" on the other hand? I assume on a Sunday (in the U.S.) all employees would be "absent."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want a query to retreive **the empno and the date** where the employee
>   was absent

In such a case you need to generate all possible dates in a given range using for example this query:

```
SELECT date '2016-07-11' + level - 1 As "DATE" from dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date '2016-07-13' - date '2016-07-11' + 1;

DATE            
-----------------
16/07/11 00:00:00
16/07/12 00:00:00
16/07/13 00:00:00
```

then use a cross join to generate all possible pairs: date+employe

```
SELECT e.empno, d."DATE"
FROM (
    SELECT date '2016-07-11' + level - 1 As "DATE" from dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date '2016-07-13' - date '2016-07-11' + 1
) d
CROSS JOIN empno e
```

and then filter existing records out (leaving only not existing pairs: empno+date) using an outer join and IS NULL condition

```
SELECT e.empno, d."DATE"
FROM (
    SELECT date '2016-07-11' + level - 1 As "DATE" from dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= date '2016-07-13' - date '2016-07-11' + 1
  ) d
CROSS JOIN EMPLOYEES e 
LEFT JOIN ATTENDANCE a 
ON ( a.empno = e.empno AND a."DATE" = d."DATE" )
WHERE a."DATE" IS NULL
order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct empno 
from EMPLOYEES e, left join ATTENDANCE a
on e.empno = a.empno  and e.date=a.date
where a.empno is NULL

Comment: there is no date in he EMPLOYEES table

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner approach here would be to use a CTE to identify all distinct days in the attendance table.

we then do a Cross join with employees table to get all possible combinations

Finally we will check the existence of the EmpNo, Date tuple in the Attendance table.

```
With Dates (date)  as (Select Distinct Date from Attendance )

Select Emp.EmpNo, dates.date from employee emp cross join Dates
where (emp.empno, dates.date) not in
(Select Empno, date from Attendance
```